# Switching to webdav from frontpage extensions on IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, webdav

We upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit with IIS 7.5 for a classic asp website. I was using frontpage server extensions before(on win2003 server). I configured webdav on the server and I successfully mapped the site as network drive to my local pc. I can open the drive, see files, make changes etc. When I open visual studio 2008 an select open website / file system/ X drive (where the mapping is), visual studio opens the site. I can view/rename/delete files but when I view and make a change then try to save the file I get ". But when I try to save I get the I get the error "The operation could not be completed. Access is denied." message. Same with when I try to add a new file. I checked all the permissions and everything seems to be good. Like I said I can change the files if I just open the mapped drive through my computer. I'm also running VS 2008 as an administrator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can edit/save files when I browse through Windows Explorer. It's just through visual studio I can not save. While enabling failed request tracing on the server, I disabled Active Server Pages(/system32/inetsrc/asp.dll) under ISAPI and CGI restrictions part of IIS. When I disable ASP, for some reason I'm able to edit/save files through visual studio on my local box. But obviously I need that enabled :) I tried to give access to asp.dll file but it doesnt let me even though I'm running an administrator account.